# Scipy method SLSQP with vector returns in constraints and objective function

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

[Edited]

Recently I work with Nelson Siegel Svensson Yield Curve Model, but I ran into a situation: search best fit of paramenters Model.

Given the above, I use simple dataset represented with Period (**const** vector) and Yield Value (**y_real** vector), to calibrate the parameters **b0, b1, b2, b3, t1** and **t2** of original function (detailed in **model** objective function with **x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]** and **x[5]** respectively) to find a minimal difference of original Yield Value vs. estimated Yield Value with the NSS Yield Curve Model using the most adjusted parameters for this purpose, so that in the end calculate interpolation and extrapolations Yields Values based on specific Periods.

**Note:** The constraint function defined with this premise fun(x) == 0 (type 'eq') to search a minimal difference between the **y_real** and result of model (in vector form), for example:

If y_real = [1.1, 1.4 ,1.3] and the result of model function is [0.2, 1.7, 3.3], then the  difference result is [0.9, -0.3, -2] and its necesary to iterate again until you get approximately zero vector in result difference, for exalmple of solution vector difference is: [1.0e-22, 1.0e-21, 1.0e-25]

I deveolped trial solution with Scipy minimize least_squares ([Calibrate parameters of Yield Curve Nelson Siegel Svensson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71846376/calibrate-parameters-of-yield-curve-nelson-siegel-svensson)) but it's a very simple form and I need more accuracy, for this some people recommended me SLSQP method of Scipy Optimize Minimize.

This is my code for search a calibrated parameters and then use in a NSS Yield Curve:

```
from numpy import array, append
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from math import exp as EXP


const = [30,90,180,270,365,730,1095,1460,1825,2190,2555,2920,3285,3650,4015,4380,4745,5110,5475,5840,6205,6570,6935,7300]

y_real = [3.11826,3.71463,3.74677,3.83900,4.00049,4.40666,4.52346,4.64026,4.75706,4.87386,4.99066,5.10746,5.22426,
          5.34106,5.44522,5.54669,5.64816,5.74963,5.85110,5.88607,5.91162,5.93717,5.96272,5.98827]

def model(x, const, y_real):

    arr = array([])
    
    for val in const:
        arr = append(arr,(x[0])+(x[1]*((1-EXP(-val/x[4]))/(val/x[4])))+(x[2]*((((1-EXP(-val/x[4]))/(val/x[4])))-(EXP(-val/x[4]))))+x[3]*((((1-EXP(-val/x[5]))/(val/x[5])))-(EXP(-val/x[5]))))
    
    return array(y_real) - arr
 

def fun(x, const, y_real):
    
    eval = model(x, const, y_real)
    
    leval = array([0 if val < 1.0e-20 else 1 for val in eval])
    
    return leval
  

con = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': fun, 'args' : (const, y_real)}


x0 = array([0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 1.0e-10, 1.0e-10])

#bounds_ = [(0.001,8),(0.001,8),(0.001,8),(0.001,8),(1.0e-15,3),(1.0e-15,3)]  bounds=bounds_

res = minimize(model, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=[con] , args=(const, y_real))

print(res)
```

but I reached one result error:

```
in _minimize_slsqp
    w = zeros(len_w)
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

How I reach the solution with SLSQP method (or another best option) with a comprehensive way without this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, I explain more about the situation in original post.

Comment: Note that the constraint function affects the trajectory of the solver, but in your case since it is not smooth (only zeros or ones), it may have no effect at all except to slow down the solver (because internally it calculates the Jacobian for the constraint through numerical differentiation, which almost always be all zeroes in this case, except when one of the elements are exactly on 1.0e-20, which is very unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your problem is probably that your `model` doesn't return a scalar value.

It's highly recommended to make yourself familiar with numpy. For instance,  given `const` and `y_real` are numpy arrays, you don't need loops and `append` to implement your `model` function. It can be written as follows (note that it returns the sum of the squared differences):

```py
import numpy as np

const = np.array([ # your values here ])
y_real = np.array([ # your values here ])

def model(x, const, y_real):
    arr = (
    x[0] + (x[1] * ((1 - np.exp(-const / x[4])) / (const / x[4])))
         + (x[2] * ((((1 - np.exp(-const / x[4])) / (const / x[4]))) 
         - (np.exp(-const / x[4]))))
         + x[3] * ((((1 - np.exp(-const / x[5])) / (const / x[5]))) 
         - (np.exp(-const / x[5])))
    )
    return np.sum((y_real - arr)**2)
```

In addition, there are a few more things that do not make sense and it's still not 100% clear to me what you are trying to achieve:

- Subtracting a vector of zeros from the evaluated model inside `fun`
- Subtracting a vector of zeros from `leval` inside `fun`
- Adding the constraint `fun(x) >= 0`. What's the purpose of this constraint? The function returns a vector consisting of zeros or ones, so this constraint is always fulfilled.

By ignoring the constraint `fun` (which, by the way, is not differentiable and contradicts the mathematical assumptions of the SLSQP algorithm), you can write:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x0 = np.array([0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 1.0e-10, 1.0e-10])
res = minimize(lambda x: model(x, const, y_real), x0, method="SLSQP")
```

Comment: Good explanation joni, it was necesary to know the least squared solution using a SLSQP method, I will also take the opportunity to clarify the purpose of the constraint function:

the constraint is fun(x) == 0 (type 'eq') to search a minimal difference between the y_real and result (in vector form of model), for example if y_real = [1.1, 1.4 ,1.3] and the result of model function is [0.2, 1.7, 3.3], the difference result is [0.9, -0.3, -2] and its necesary to iterate again until you get approximately zero vector in result difference, for exalmple: [1.0e-12, 1.0e-15, 1.0e-18].

Comment: @MichaelDePaz Good catch, I missed that it's 'eq' instead of 'ineq'. Nonetheless, the constraint is not needed. Minimizing the sum of squared differences guarantees that each difference (i.e. each component of the vector result - y_real) is as small as possible.

Comment: You're right @joni it's a functional solution, due to this, I made a solution proposal using least squared with a simple least_squares of Scipy library (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71846376/calibrate-parameters-of-yield-curve-nelson-siegel-svensson) but now I search a solution with aprox. zero difference between real values of y_real and result of model to optimize the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Team

In order to this case, I worked part of functional solution using perspective and some good tips of @joni in previos answer (very kind for that), it's only a part because works approximately for first third segment of dataset, to work with rest of dataset segment can use the previous case code ([Calibrate parameters of Yield Curve Nelson Siegel Svensson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71846376/calibrate-parameters-of-yield-curve-nelson-siegel-svensson)).

I share with you to reuse and get idea of one possible solution in two parts, please discuss if you have a more sofistified solution

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
from math import trunc
from nelson_siegel_svensson import NelsonSiegelSvenssonCurve
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# days
const = np.array([30,90,270,548,913,1278,1643,2008,2373,2738,3103,3468,3833,4198,4563,4928,5293,5658,6023,6388,6935,7300,7665,8030])/365


# empty values represented with 0
y_real = np.array([3.33156,3.44928,3.62778,3.74313,3.96015,4.384,4.4705,4.55701,4.63817,4.69949,4.76081,4.82213,4.87285,4.8681,4.86336,4.85861,4.85387,4.84912,4.87039,4.89833,4.94286,4.98739,5.03192,5.07645])

def model(x, const, y_real):
    
    arr = np.array([])
    for val in const:
        arr = np.append(arr,(x[0])+(x[1]*((1-np.exp(-val/x[4]))/(val/x[4])))+(x[2]*((((1-np.exp(-val/x[4]))/(val/x[4])))-(np.exp(-val/x[4]))))+x[3]*((((1-np.exp(-val/x[5]))/(val/x[5])))-(np.exp(-val/x[5]))))
    
    return np.sum((y_real - arr)**2)


# initial coefficients of Nelson Siegel Svensson
x0 = np.array([0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 1.0e-10, 1.0e-10])

res = minimize(model, x0, method='SLSQP', args=(const, y_real), 
               options={'maxiter': 10000, 'ftol': 1e-190})
 
print(res.x)

X_fix = np.linspace(start=const[0], stop=const[-1], num=(const.size*20))

NSS = NelsonSiegelSvenssonCurve(beta0=res.x[0], beta1=res.x[1], beta2=res.x[2], beta3=res.x[3], tau1=res.x[4], tau2=res.x[5])

pd_interpolation = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Period','Value'])

font = {'family': 'serif',
    'color':  '#1F618D',
    'weight': 'bold',
    'size': 14,
    }

font_x_y = {'family': 'serif',
    'color':  '#C70039',
    'weight': 'bold',
    'size': 13,
    'style': 'oblique' 
    }

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 6))

minx = -const[1]*3

config_manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
config_manager.set_window_title("Visualización " )

screen_x, screen_y = config_manager.window.wm_maxsize()

anchura = str(trunc(screen_x/12))
altura = str(trunc(screen_y/8))
middle_window = "+" + anchura + "+" + altura

config_manager.window.wm_geometry(middle_window)

plt.title('Interpolación ', fontdict=font, loc='center')
plt.xlabel('Periodo', fontdict=font_x_y)
plt.ylabel('Aproximación', fontdict=font_x_y, rotation=90, labelpad=10)

ax.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=(np.amax(y_real)*1.1))
ax.set_xlim(xmin=minx, xmax=(np.amax(const)*1.03))

ax.plot(const, y_real, 'ro', label='Dato real')
ax.plot(X_fix, NSS(X_fix),'--', label='Dato interpolado')
ax.legend(loc='lower right', frameon=False)

plt.show()
```

And result graph is this:

[image]